# Fetch the name of Linked Entry in Contentful API

Tags: contentful

I'm using Contentful API to get the details of all the entries in a Space, is there a way to fetch the name of 'linked entry/entries' to a particular entry? In this case, i'm fetching all the entries with the content_type = HorizontalImageCard and then that each entry has link to other entries(could be a link to an Asset or link to different Contentul entry), and i would like to get the name of such entries, attaching the screenshot of what i'm looking for, in the screenshot there's a Linked Entry called 'Jennifer Test', how do i fetch that name?

```
let fetchRes = fetch("https://preview.contentful.com/spaces/{space_id}/environments/ca/entries/{entry_id}?access_token=vOKxCDyhU8gLUsU4FR5tgdwQVe3arwfJzFTCloi2sjM&content_type=HorizontalImageCard");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the GraphQL API? I didn't get a chance to try it out with the REST API, but I was able to get the result with the GraphQL API. Here's an example query:

```
{
  userCollection(preview:true) {
    items {
      name
      linkedFrom {
        blogArticleCollection {
          items {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The User content type is linked in the Blog Article content type. This method allows me to list all those references. Hope this helps :)

Comment: hmm, let me give a try, thanks @harshil1712